# I was asked to discuss my question in meta

Tags: discussion

[What secure and good options are there for hosting own private mail server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/824988/what-secure-and-good-options-are-there-for-hosting-own-private-mail-server)

Somehow the questions asked are not related to the topic of the forum which is for questions about:

- managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or networks
- tools used for administering, monitoring, or automating these
- deployment to and management of third-party provided information technology platforms

Answer (score 16):

I'll take your question point by point.

> What secure and good options are there for hosting own private mail
>   server?

Off-topic: product recommendation.

> is it really worth it to have a separate VPS just for running postfix?

No one can answer this except for you. None of us know your requirements nor how much anything is worth to you.

> Would it be fast and effective? How would it work against spam
>   filters?

How long is a piece of string? Honestly, how good are you at administering an email system? If you're having to ask these questions, it's probably not something you're skilled at.

> Is there a better way to do that from within my google cloud solution?

Off topic: opinion-based.

> Is it a better idea to keep the google cloud website/service separate
>   from the e-mail server for security reasons?

Off topic: opinion-based.

> What is common practice in the field?

Too broad.

> Would you advice against or for using SendGrid, Mailgun or Mailjet for
>   my daily email?

Off-topic: both opinion-based and product recommendation.

> Would using AWS resolve all of my problems and be better fit for my
>   use?

Off-topic: too broad.